# purrr placeholder: alternative coding

Tags: r, purrr

I have list like this:

```
l <- list("patients" = patients, 
          "patient_orders" = patient_orders,
          "specimen_info" = specimen_info, 
          "hasta_test_bilgi" = hasta_test_bilgi, 
          "patient_reports_rerun" = patient_reports_rerun,
          "diagnosis" = diagnosis)
```

All list items are tibbles and I want to write each tibble to seperate .csv file with list names.

I can accomplish this by following code:

```
walk2(.x = l,.y = glue("output/{names(l)}.csv"),  .f = write_excel_csv)
```

Is there any elegant way to accomplish this to perform this operation:
I searched for purrr documentation for placeholder like . to use walk()

Thanks

Comment: How exactly is this not elegant?

Comment: What is your definition of "elegant"? What is wrong with this line currently?

Comment: I am using walk2 but I think it is also possible with walk. Dplyr has . as reference. Just trying to learn purrr efficiently...

Comment: I guess with `walk` you can do something like this: `library(glue); library(purrr); walk(names(l), ~ write_excel_csv(l[.], glue_data(., "output/{.}.csv")))` Can't test it though since your question is not reproducible

Comment: @useR thanks for your reply!!! With your suggestion I found answer:
`walk(names(l), ~ write_excel_csv(l[[.]], glue("output/111{.}.csv"))) `

Comment: If using the list and the names of the list, `iwalk` might be useful here.  Then the list is `.x` and the names of the list is `.y` in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need to go through both names and content of a list, use the `imap` subfamily, which includes `iwalk` that we'll use here.

These are all equivalent:

```
walk2(.x = l,.y = glue("{names(l)}.csv"),  .f = write.csv)
walk(names(l), ~ write.csv(l[[.]], glue("{.}.csv")))
iwalk(l,~write.csv(.x,glue("{.y}.csv")))
l %>% set_names(glue("{names(.)}.csv")) %>% iwalk(write.csv)
```